# Read/write file in location other than external storage using Robolectric

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

My app reads files in /proc.  I am trying to test this with Robolectric 2.3.

I can create a test file in the "external storage" without problems:

```
ShadowEnvironment.setExternalStorageState(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
PrintWriter out;
out = new PrintWriter("myFile");
out.println(contents);
```

However if I try to write to a file in `/proc` it blows up with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \proc\net\netstat (Access is denied)`.

```
ShadowEnvironment.setExternalStorageState(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
boolean a = new File( "/proc" ).mkdirs();  //Fails
PrintWriter out;
out = new PrintWriter("/proc/myFile");
out.println(contents);
```

Is there any way I can cause a (specific) file to exist in /proc, for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered similar questions today. Looks like today is day about promoting single class responsibility and dependency injections.

I would change your code to next first:

- Write a class that will be responsible for opening (closing, other operations, keep an eye that it should be simple) file connections
- Make a class that reads information from stream/file to some internal data structure
- Process this data in your original class

Next I would write tests:

- Check file operations class
- Check that reader is passing correct file location to file operations class instance (mock in tests)
- Check that original class correctly process information that is provided by reader class (reader is mocked in tests)

Hope it helps!